# Notification with dynamic cell range as body of the email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have values from column A to J.

I have dates in column G. I want to check if the value in column G is today's date to send an email.

The email should have the values of those columns where the date matches today's date + 14 days (notification 14 days prior to the due date).

Also, the recipient in the To field should be picked from column I and CC picked  from column J along with some predefined ones.

If there are multiple rows which match the current date, it should generate multiple emails.

Code from net and modified.

```
Sub method1()

For i = 2 To 6
    If Day(VBA.Date) = Day(Range("c" & i).Value) And Month(VBA.Date) = Month(Range("c" & i).Value) Then
        Call sendbday(Range("a" & i).Value, Range("b" & i).Value)
    End If
Next

End Sub

Sub sendbday(name_to As String, b_to As String)
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim body_text As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

' Use weblink to  add the image in the email body
body_text = "<p> <p align='left'><font size='2' face='arial' color='blue'><i> Hello " & name_to & ", </p>" & vbNewLine

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = b_to
    .Cc = " "
    .Subject = "Notification Alert " & name_to & " !!"
    .htmlBody = body_text
    .display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post example of your spreadsheet